# Shader doesn't have a texture property '_MainTex'

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, textures

The wacky thing is I ran my code once and it worked like a charm. The line of code I'm getting the error on is:

```
exampleTexture = (Texture2D)rend.material.mainTexture;
```

I know that the custom shader I'm using has something other than 'mainTexture', it's something along the lines of:

```
Properties
    {
        _Example ("Example (R16)", 2D) = "black" {}
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
    }
```

I'm just stumped as it worked the first time, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you look into [`Material.mainTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-mainTexture.html) and also the [source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/3f0dae724475e51dab2c924c4fa470cfd0269280/Runtime/Export/Shaders/Material.bindings.cs#L59) you can see that there are two things this can refer to

- Either you have a shader property which is attributed with [`[MainTexture]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.ShaderPropertyFlags.MainTexture.html)
- or as  fallback it is looking for `_MainTex`.

Or in the word of the API

> By default, Unity considers a texture with the property name `"_MainTex"` to be the main texture. Use the `[MainTexture]` ShaderLab Properties attribute to make Unity consider a texture with a different property name to be the main texture.

Both is not the case in your shader.

You would probably want to rename `Example` to

```
_MainTex ("Example (R16)", 2D) = "black" {}
```

or if you want/need to stick to the name `_Example` you will need to add the mentioned attribute

```
 [MainTexture] _Example ("Example (R16)", 2D) = "black" {}
```

---

Or alternatively do not use the default property accessors but rather use the more generic [`Material.GetTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.GetTexture.html)

```
exampleTexture = (Texture2D)rend.material.GetTexture("_Example");
```

Comment: I unfortunately don't have the option to edit the shader or it's code in any way

Comment: In that case you will want to go for the alternative option at the bottom

Comment: I used GetTexture and it worked! Cheers!